# Fast determinant of an Alexander matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant, knot-theory

I want to compute the determinant of a polynomial $n \times n$ matrix where each entry is a univariate polynomial of degree at most $1$. I calculated it naively and was quickly reminded of how fast $n!$ grows. I know there are faster methods for scalar matrices like the LU decomposition but I'm not sure if they can be generalised to polynomial matrices. I have seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518/1006266) a way around the problem which computes $n$ scalar determinants but it is a little too involved for me, is there anything simpler but still practical?

Since I am computing the [Alexander polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial) of a knot, my matrix is the [Alexander matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_matrix).

Comment: The method you link to only computes $n$ determinants in your case, not $2n$. In what sense do you find it "a little too involved"? (Without knowing that, it's hard to know what you would consider "simpler".)

Comment: Of course, if the degree of your polynomial is $>n$, it is valuable to use Cayley-Hamilton to reduce it to a degree $n$ polynomial (even if it is cost-effective to compute the characteristic polynomial. Once more, a trade-off issue...

Comment: The determinant has degree $\le n$ so if you evaluate it for $n+1$ distinct values of $x$ you can uniquely "reconstruct" the polynomial via interpolation. AFAICT that's the idea in the post you linked, only it's $n+1$ scalar determinants, not $2n$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, that method does indeed only compute $n$ determinants (my polynomials have degree 1 not 2). My problem with that method was the interpolation part. But if all other methods are more complicated I'll go with that. @dxiv

Comment: @MarcoMendívilCarboni Then can't you write your matrix-valued function as $A (x) := A_0 + x A_1$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, does that simplify calculating its determinant? Sorry I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @MarcoMendívilCarboni Ever heard of [matrix pencils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil)?  One could argue that you have a [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I had not (I only know what the eigenvalues of a single matrix are). I see, that's an interesting way to see the problem do you think solving the corresponding generalised eigenvalue problem could be a better way to go?

Comment: @MarcoMendívilCarboni Whether you think of it as a generalized characteristic polynomial or not may make no difference. However, if matrices $A_0$ and $A_1$ have "structure" or are "special", then it's easier.  For example, are they diagonal or rank-1?  It would be easier if you provided motivation for this question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm unaware of any structure in this matrices. Regarding the motivation what I'm atually computing is the [Alexander polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial) of a knot so my matrix is the Alexander matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144578/discussion-between-marco-mendivil-carboni-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Comment: @MarcoMendívilCarboni I wonder if the  generalized eigenvalues of the Alexander matrix provide any useful information.  Perhaps the "generalized spectrum" of the knot.  Have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a presentation of the fundamental group of the knot complement first before calculating a presentation matrix for the Alexander module (the Alexander polynomial is purely a property of the fundamental group after all). It looks like I posted some Mathematica code snippets [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekmill/tools/code_snippets.html) that might be useful (though you should not consider it to be well-tested code).

One of the main issues with working with the Alexander module is that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$ is not a principal ideal domain. However, you can pass to $\mathbb{Q}[t^{\pm 1}]$ and compute determinants (potentially using the theorem that the Alexander polynomial evaluated at $t=1$ is $1$ to find the right scaling factor for the result, depending on how you go about calculating things). This is a PID, so you can compute Smith Normal Form, and from there the determinant is easy.

Likewise, another approach is that you can pass to the field $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ of rational functions and do Gaussian elimination to compute the determinant. This is an $O(n^3)$ algorithm (ignoring complexity from the degrees of the polynomials), and there is no need to use the $O(n!)$ algorithm when you are working over a field.

In [KnotFolio](https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/) I do some fundamental group simplifications then do a half-hearted attempt at computing something like a Smith Normal Form (which doesn't always exist over $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$) before doing cofactor expansions. Part of this is that I wanted to see the Alexander module presentation matrix in a reasonably simplified form, since it's interesting to know when the Alexander polynomial factorizes even though the presentation matrix isn't block diagonal. This is an algebraic property you lose when you work even over just $\mathbb{Q}[t^{\pm 1}]$.